# How can I restore part of a mailbox from an RDB?

Tags: exchange-2010, restore, backupexec

I need to restore only part of a mailbox that was deleted by accident.  I restored the database and tried to associate it to a dummy test account but get the error

> Failed
>
> Error: The mailbox that you specified is connected to "asdf, asdf
>    ". Only disconnected mailboxes can be reconnected. Specified
>   mailbox: "b79e5853-ce6d-466c-b2c7-asdfasdfasdf". Click here for
>   help...
>   http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms.exch.err.default(EXCHG.141).aspx?v=14.2.342.0&t=exchgf1&e=ms.exch.err.ExC386D7
>
> Exchange Management Shell command attempted: Connect-Mailbox -Identity
>   'b79e5853-ce6d-466c-b2c7-asdfasdfasdf' -Database 'recover3' -User
>   'company\testperms' -Alias 'test123'
>
> Elapsed Time: 00:00:00

How can I gain access to the data within the mailbox and export it so that it can be restored in the target mailbox (without overwriting existing data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We handle this by restoring the database to a new recovery DB, and restoring the mailbox to a temp/dummy mailbox (such as "Recovery JLyons" for myself):

```
New-MailboxRestoreRequest -Name Restore001 -SourceDatabase RDB01 -SourceStoreMailbox "Jeremy Lyons" -TargetMailbox "Recovery JLyons" -AllowLegacyDNMismatch
```

Monitor the restore, Ctrl-C to break:

```
while ($true) { Get-MailboxRestoreRequest Restore001 | Get-MailboxRestoreRequestStatistics; sleep 60; }
```

Once the restore is complete, you can either assign Jeremy Lyons Full Access permissions to the "Recovery JLyons" mailbox and let me pick what I need out of it in Outlook, or you can export it to a PST:

```
New-MailboxExportRequest -Name Export001 -Mailbox "Recovery JLyons" -FilePath "\\fileserver\Users\JLyons\recovery_jlyons.pst"
```

Monitor the export, Ctrl-C to break:

```
while ($true) { Get-MailboxExportRequest Export001 | Get-MailboxExportRequestStatistics; sleep 60; }
```